# Record a time when an attachment column is modified in SharePoint List

Tags: power-automate

I have a SharePoint List where linked to PowerApps. In the list, I have a column called "Attachment Time" and "Modification Type".

I wanted to create a flow that runs when an attachment has been uploaded/Modified/Deleted. Once the flow is triggered, I want the "Attachment Time" Column to be updated to the modified time and the "Modification Type" to display when the action was Uploaded/Modified/Deleted.

If nothing was done to the list Item since the time it was created, I want the "Attachment Time" to be the "Created" column value and the "Modification Type" column to stay empty.

I wanted all this to be done in Power Automate but I am somehow stuck on the conditioning. It would be great if I get the solution to both columns but if not then the information to the  "Attachment Time" column would be great.